# Cannot get data from third table using relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables, structure are as follows:

```
products:
id | name | slug | price

product_attributes:
id | attribute_id | value | qty | product_id

attributes :
id | code | name
```

Now i'm getting the product and the attributes selected for this particular product using the following relationships but i also want the code and name of the attribute from the third table i.e. attributes:

> ProductController.php:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->findProductBySlug($slug);
    return view('site.pages.product', compact('product'));
}
```

> ProductRepository.php

```
   public function findProductBySlug($slug)
    {
    $product = Product::with('attributes')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return $product;
    }
```

> Model : Product.php

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class);
}
```

getting data on view with following code:

`{{ dd($product->attributes) }}`

but i also want data from the third table i.e. attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Many to Many relationship and withPivot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to get the pivot attributes:

```php
// Product Model:
public function attributes()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes')->withPivot('value', 'qty');
}


// Attribute Model:
public function products()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_attributes')->withPivot('value', 'qty');
}
```

So you can get attributes and the pivot's datas:

```php
@foreach($product->attributes as $attr)
    {{$attr->pivot->value}}
    {{$attr->pivot->qty}}
    {{$attr->code}}
    {{$attr->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want the fields to be displayed from the third table i.e. attributes which contains code and name.I'm getting the data from product table and product_attributes table using the relation in my question

Comment: @user3653474 `$product->attributes` will get all the `attributes`, and you can use `$attr->code` and `$attr->name` to get from the third table.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define a relation between `Product` and `ProductAttribute`

> Model : Product.php

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Then you need to define a relation between `ProductAttribute` and `Attribute` model

> Model : Attribute.php

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

Then you can eager load relations easily by `.` notation

```
public function findProductBySlug($slug)
{
 $product = Product::with('attributes.attributes')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

 return $product;
}
```